# Is police clearance required for study permit/visa for Canada?

Tags: germany, canada, student-visa, bangladeshi-citizens

Is police clearance documents required for a person who is a citizen & passport-holder of Bangladesh, lives in Germany (0.5 – 3 years) and now wants to apply for study permit/visa to study in Canada?

**Additional Question:** Which country would be convenient for his Visa application, Bangladesh or Germany? Why?

Answer (score 1):

It is advised to apply from the home country, so that they can verify all the details, like what are your ties to the country and your financial stability, etc.
Thus applying for Bangladesh would be much better than applying from Germany.

Also they verify all the details, so a police clearance might be sought. See 
[Avoiding Delays in Study Permit Processing](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/publications/delay.asp)